# User selected number of objects per page in Django

Tags: python, django

I made pagination for my site but I want to let the user choose how many records are displayed at one time e.g. 10, 15, 25. This is my views.py

```
def finished_ads_view(request):
    queryset = Campaign.objects.filter(completion_percent=100)

    try:
        per_page = request.GET['dropdown']
    except:
        per_page = 1

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(queryset, per_page)

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'posts': posts,
    }

    return render(request, 'finished_campaigns.html', context)
```

And this is part of my template:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        {% if posts.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="?page=1" aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">begin</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}

        {% for n in posts.paginator.page_range %}
          {% if posts.number == n %}
            <li class="page-item active">
              <span class="page-link">{{ n }}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>
            </li>
          {% elif n > posts.number|add:'-3' and n < posts.number|add:'3' %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ n }}">{{ n }}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if posts.has_next %}
          <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}" aria-label="Next">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
              <span class="sr-only">end</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>

    <select name="dropdown">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The problem is that the dropdown value does not change and the number of records displayed at one time is still the same as the except: per_page value.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your select and submit in a form so the value gets passed to the backend in query string.

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="{{ page }}">
    ...
</form>
```

Also pagination parameter needs to be included so I added that. You need to add it to the context as well. Then when creating links for the pages with GET attribute don't forget to pass the `dropdown` as well.

Comment: in question page is not exists in content

Comment: yes it needs to be added as it is clearly used see `request.GET.get('page', 1)`

Answer (score 1):

To see the whole template can be better. I can only imagine:

```
<form>
<-- any staff here -->
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="{{ request.GET.page }}">
<-- any staff here -->
<select name="dropdown">
    <option {% if request.GET.dropdown == "1" %}selected{% endif %} 
 value="1">1</option>
    <option {% if request.GET.dropdown == "2" %}selected{% endif %} 
 value="2">2</option>
    <option {% if request.GET.dropdown == "15" %}selected{% endif %} value="15">15</option>
    <option {% if request.GET.dropdown == "20" %}selected{% endif %} value="20">20</option>
</select>
<-- any staff here -->
<input type="submit" />
<-- any staff here -->
</form>
```

Dont forget to add request in context, if you don't have `request context processor`.

Comment: I edited the question now you can see the whole pagination thing in the template